# Activity crashing on resume

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the following in OnCreate

```
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

On resume is:

```
  @Override
  public void onResume(){

     onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     super.onResume();

  }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    context = this;
    ps = PuzzleState.getInstance();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pack_list);
    }
```

It throws the exception when activity resumes: rewuestFeature must be called before adding content. Whats wrong ?

Comment: Why are you calling onCreate() through your code?

Comment: When the activity is in background, some parameters changes and this requires GUI changes. onCreate() is called to make sure that changed parameters are reflected in GUI.

Comment: You can move the initialization code into onResume().

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `setContentView` in `onCreate`

Comment: Its being called before setContentView in onCreate. It works fine normally but crashing while resuming.

Comment: Its is because when you call onCreate on resume  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  will be invoked after setting the contentview. This is because onCreate will be called twice and during the first call content view will be set in the activity. You must not call requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) on onResume.

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) is called only in onCreate(). onResume() is calling onCreate(). I have edited question with complete code on onCreate().

Comment: That means on create will be called twice.And on the second call requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) will be called after setting the contentView

Answer (score 1):

If you were set **requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);** after onCreate() method then you have to remove that and set

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery_item);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this working - I got this idea only after reading all comments and solutions offered. Thanks to all who responded.

```
      private static boolean first = true;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;

      if(first){

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        first = false;
      }


      context = this;
      ps = PuzzleState.getInstance();
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_pack_list);
       }
```